# QML Reference Error - <thing> is not defined during a c++/QML integration

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, integration

I am trying to build a mixed c++/QML application but I came across a problem when trying to make both parts communicate and interact.
The objective is to use embedded C++ object in QML via the setContextProperties method, using QQmlApplicationEngine.

I've been looking at this post [QT 5.7 QML - Reference Error: Class is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543883/qt-5-7-qml-reference-error-class-is-not-defined) since the problem is quite similar, but unfortunately the solution doesn't apply here. I'm still new to Qt so maybe the solution is obvious but I couldn't figure it out.

So I have 3 files, `main.cpp`, `thing.h` and `main.qml`.

main.cpp:

```
#include "thing.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    Thing thing;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("thing", &thing);
    thing.setColor(Qt::green);

    return app.exec();
}
```

which calls thing.h:

```
class Thing : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor NOTIFY colorChanged)

public:
    Thing() : _color(Qt::black), _text("text") { }

    Q_INVOKABLE void clicked() { setColor(Qt::blue); }

    QColor color() const {return _color;}
    void setColor(const QColor &color) {
        _color = color;
        emit colorChanged();
    }
signals:
    void colorChanged();

private:
    QColor _color;
};
```

and main.qml:

```
Window {id: main
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: thing.color

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: thing.clicked();
    }
}
```

When running this code, I get 'qrc:/main.qml:6: ReferenceError: thing is not defined' which refers to the execution `color: thing.color` in main.qml. How can I get it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to expose your root context property "thing" before loading your main component. It will ensure that your "thing" property will be available once the component instance is created and its bindings are evaluated for the first time.

```
#include "thing.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Thing thing;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("thing", &thing);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    thing.setColor(Qt::green);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jbh, this was it !